# How add a network printer with command line to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: juju, maas

Description:

In MAAS i need a node with a network printer , so I need some command to add in JUJU install to add network printer .

If there is a solution let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need a charm for the relevant service. Do you have a preferred one?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

1. Install  lpadmin
2. using lpadmin commands to add default printer
3. here are useful links:

   - https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/cups.html
   - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1423730
4. There is another solution:

   - https://pdfbox.apache.org/